# Isomorphism between $V(x,y)\subset\Bbb A^3$ and $\operatorname{Spec}(k[x])$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{A}_k^1 := \operatorname{Spec}(k[x])$ where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. I cannot see the isomorphism between $V(x,y) \subset \mathbb{A}_k^3$ and $\mathbb{A}_k^1$. It should be trivial but I think that my problem is that I can't see what the prime ideals of $V(x,y)$ really are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will write $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ as Spec$(k[z])$ not Spec$(k[x])$ for simplicity of the argument.

We have a map $\pi:k[x,y,z]\to k[z]$ given by evaluating $x=y=0$. This is a ring homomorphism. Therefore, by functoriality of Spec, there is an associated map Spec$(\pi):\mathbb{A}^1_k\to \mathbb{A}^3_k$. A maximal ideal $(z-a)\in$Spec$(k[z])$ is sent to $(x,y,z-a)\in$Spec$(k[x,y,z])$. The other prime $(0)$ is sent to $(x,y)$. All of these are actually points of $V(x,y)$ as the points of $V(x,y)$ are just those primes of $k[x,y,z]$ containing $(x,y)$.

Comment: To be precise, you want to evaluate at $x=y=0$ and send $z$ to $x$.

Comment: Yes, that's right, sorry.

Comment: But what Is the preimage of $(z)$ and (y)? Are also them prime ideals of $V(x,y)$, aren't they?

Comment: No, $(y)$ and $(z)$ are not prime ideals of $V(x,y)$. A prime ideal of $V(x,y)$ is a prime ideal of $k[x,y,z]$ containing $(x,y)$. Since $(x,y)$ is not contained in $(y)$ or in $(z)$, these are not primes of $V(x,y)$. Therefore, Spec$(\pi)^{-1}((z))=\emptyset$ and the same for $(y)$, since niether is in the image which is $V(x,y)$.

Comment: To get the terminology straight: $V(x, y)$ is a scheme, not a ring, so it does not have prime ideals, it has points. And points of $V(x,y)$ are prime ideals of $k[x,y,z]$ containing the ideal $(x,y)$.

Comment: Good point Vladimir!